# Dot and hyphen disallowed React Router URL parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working to implement an image viewer and using React Router.  Uploaded image files are of the format `<name>.<type-suffix>-<date-tag>`, with a period and a hypen as delimiters.

Given this route: `<Route path="zoomer/:imageId" component={ Zoom }/>` and this URL `http://localhost:8080/zoomer/medMain.tif-1461839237863` it does not seem that the router is finding a match.

If I remove the dot and the hyphen (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/zoomer/medMaintif1461839237863`) routing works just fine, but I really need to keep those delimiters for semantic reasons.  And URLEncode() won't help me here, either.

Is there something I need to do with the Route spec to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue proved to be webpack dev server with history-api-fallback enabled failed to pass these urls to the react app. Hacked webpack config to pass these to react with:

```
...
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/*.*': { // Match all URL's with period/dot
      target: 'http://localhost:8080/',  // send to webpack dev server
      rewrite: function(req){
        req.url='index.html';  // Send to react app
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 19):

Adding this to your webpack devServer config also does the trick:

```
historyApiFallback: {
    disableDotRule: true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Vite** then this plugin will solve the issue:

#### Install it as a dev dependency

`npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-rewrite-all`

#### Add the plugin to your vite.conf.js file

```js
import pluginRewriteAll from 'vite-plugin-rewrite-all'; // <= import the plugin


export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    pluginRewriteAll() // <= add the new plugin
  ],
})
```

Source: https://github.com/ivesia/vite-plugin-rewrite-all

Comment: Saved me many hours of work, thanks so much!

Comment: If anybody find `This package is ESM only but it was tried to load by require` error. Just renaming `vite.config.js/vite.config.ts` to `vite.config.mjs/vite.config.mts`