# React Router : Cannot GET with email address as params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have a router setup like this.

```
<Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <Route path="emailactivation/code/:email" component={EmailActivationCode} />
```

But when I access the page it returns an error and does not load the component correctly.

```
Cannot GET /emailactivation/code/test@email.com
```

I am using webpack-dev-server for the local server.
How can I put an email address as the parameter for the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's because of the dot (email.com) in the path that you have provided. Try programmatically changing it (e.g. replace dot with %dot% before providing the link, then revert it in your component).

Comment: Yes, I did test that. It is because of the . (dot) in .com.
Replacing the (dot) might be a problem due to various type of email domain extensions (such as :.co.uk, .something.or.idk, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue today and I had to update my webpack config to

> historyApiFallback: {
> disableDotRule: true
> }

based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52476492/836008

Posting here in case anyone lands here