# Reactstrap Navbar link to PDF not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I for some reason cannot get this simple link to a PDF to work. I am using react, reactstrap navbar with bootstrap css. Here is an example of my issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/n3yqk17q8l

I must be missing something simple. Thanks for your time!

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
Collapse,
Navbar,
NavbarToggler,
NavbarBrand,
Nav,
NavItem,
NavLink
} from "reactstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <Navbar color="dark" dark expand="sm">
        <NavbarBrand href="/">Brand</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler />
        <Collapse navbar>
        <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="/sample.pdf">
                <span className="fa fa-fw fa-file-pdf" /> PDF
            </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
        </Nav>
        </Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    </div>
);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavLink href="/sample.pdf">
```

You need to remove the dot from this url. Is there any reason that you need to include the dot in the pdf link?
For exmple, this will work

```
 <NavLink href="/sample">
```

Comment: Well I'd prefer to keep the file extension in order for the browser to know what to do with the file when it retrieves it.

Comment: then I guess you need to customize webpack configuration.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923466/dot-and-hyphen-disallowed-react-router-url-parameters