# React router allow path with dot(.)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I was trying to add regex to allow paths like below, but i was not able to make it work. 
eg:

1. `'/hello/search.apple.tree'`
2. `'/hello/search.mango.tr'`
3. `'/view/location.chicago.illinois'`
4. `'/view/location.boston.ma'`

Comment: could you please show the router code? to see what routes are you enabling..

Comment: Maybe this is an answer you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923466/dot-and-hyphen-disallowed-react-router-url-parameters/52476492

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can resolve by adding this to you webpack dev server config.

```
historyApiFallback: {
    disableDotRule: true
}
```

from: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3409

Answer (score 1):

React is using a library for the path ([see react documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string)) 
The library is called [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0)

You have to check what are the valid paths you can use with this lib.

Here is a demo you can try live: [valid path demo](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/)